# selecting columns from one table or another

Tags: mysql

Say I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE state (
    id TINYINT,
    state CHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE valid_state (
    id INT,
    state CHAR(2), # or stateId TINYINT or whatever
    productId INT
);
```

If a product can only be sold in CA it'll have a single entry in valid_state. If it can be sold in all states there won't be any entries in valid_state. If it can't be sold in any state the product needs to be disabled in the undefined products table.

My question is this: how can I select all the valid states for a given product? Ideally I'd want to select from valid_state, see if it was empty, and if it was, then just return all states. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas?

(also, fwiw, I didn't design the schema so suggesting I change it isn't that helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is with using `UNION` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Id, 
   S.State
FROM State S
   JOIN valid_state V ON S.State = V.State AND V.ProductId = @ProductId
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT S.Id, 
   S.State
FROM State S
WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM valid_state WHERE ProductId = @ProductId)
```

Here is the sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6d47/1).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different approach.

I get all the states and mark which of those is valid for a given product with the first LEFT JOIN.

With the second LEFT JOIN I take the all the states that product is valid for and join together. Without the V.id = V2.id I'd have valid_states * 2 rows returned but with it I just have the ones I want.

```
SELECT S.Id, S.State
FROM state S
LEFT JOIN valid_state V
  ON V.state = S.state
    AND productId = @ProductId
LEFT JOIN (state S2, valid_state V2)
    ON V2.productId = @ProductId
        AND S2.state = S.state
WHERE V.id = V2.id OR V2.id IS NULL;
```

I don't know which one is better. The EXPLAIN for sgeddes shows that it's looking through 3*3*3 rows whereas mine is  doing 3*3*3*3. But sgeddes has five columns in the EXPLAIN (two of which have NULL for rows) and is "using temporary", "using join buffer" and has an "impossible WHERE"

Any ideas?